# Real time update of Data(CDC approach) from mysql to HDFS or Hive table

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, apache-kafka, real-time

I have installed `CDH 5.16` in a RHEL 7 server and installed `kafka` separately.
I am trying to load data from `mysql` to `HDFS` or `Hive` table on real time basis(`CDC` approach). That is if some data is updated or added in `mysql table` ,it should be immediately reflected in `HDFS` or `Hive` table.

Approach i have come up with:

Use `kafka-connect` to connect to `mysql` server and push table data to a  `kafka` topic 
   and write a consumer code in `spark-stream` which reads the data from topic 
   and store it in `HDFS`.
   One problem with this approach is, hive table on top of these files should 
   be refreshed periodically for the update to be reflected.

I also came to know of `Kafka-Hive` integration in HDP 3.1. Unfortunately i am using `Hadoop 2.6.0`. So cant leverage this feature.

Is there any other better way achieve this?

I am using `Hadoop 2.6.0` and `CDH 5.16.1`

Comment: are you using Confluent Kafka Connect HDFS https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-hdfs/index.html

Comment: i am not using confluent Kafka. i am having trouble in setting up confluent kafka. Also i was wondering whether this is achievable using any other method or tools apart from kafka.